# Angular universal SSR: For a built project, how do I make angular call localhost when in server and an IP when on client?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

We modified an angular project to universal. We therefore hit the IP everytime a click action happens. The angular project and our server reside on the same machine, so I would like to hit localhost when it is run server side and the IP when it is being handled by the client browser.

What is the best minimalist way to go about it?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear, I meant that, when a user takes an action on the client side, after it is loaded, some requests are sent to the server. So I want to be able to differentiate between those that happen in the browser and those that happen in via the SSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the code is being run on the server or client with:

```
import { isPlatformServer, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

if (isPlatformServer) {
  // run code on server
}

if (isPlatformBrowser) {
  // run code on the client
}
```

Use this anywhere where you need special behaviour or where you use things such as `window` or other client-specific objects.